# Filtering a numbered ArrayList<String> that contains Duplicates in android

Tags: android, arraylist, filter

When I try to filter an Arraylist which contains Duplicates the following happens:

Contents of ArrayList:

1. Cow
2. Sheep
3. Lamb
4. Chicken
5. Cow
6. Sheep

When I try to filter "cow" for example, I get this:

```
1. Cow 
1. Cow
```

My Code:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemView.setLongClickable(true);
            row = mData.get(position);
                index = list.indexOf(row);
                holder.myTextView.setText(index + 1 + ". " + row);
            }
```

What I want the output to be:

```
1. Cow
5. Cow
```

Thanks for you help !

Comment: the `list.filter()` functions returns you all elements that are matching your predicate. So you have to invert it. Do `list.filter{ it != "Cow" }` to get all items that is not "Cow"

Comment: I edited the question, the result is 1. Cow; 1. Cow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** After your edit and realizing what you need I came up with this idea. Check this code, this is for `API >= 24`:

**NOTE:** If you want your values to stay in the same order as they are inserted then use `LinkedHashMap` otherwise you can use `HashMap`.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Cow");
        list.add("Sheep");
        list.add("Lamb");
        list.add("Cow");
        list.add("Chicken");
        list.add("Sheep");
        Map<String, List<Integer>> indexes = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        indexes.computeIfAbsent(list.get(i), c -> new ArrayList<>()).add(i);
}
        System.out.println(indexes);
    }
}
```

Output to this is:

```
{Sheep=[1, 5], Chicken=[4], Cow=[0, 3], Lamb=[2]}
```

Output to this using `LinkedHashMap`:

```
{Cow=[0, 3], Sheep=[1, 5], Lamb=[2], Chicken=[4]}
```

This returns indexes of the position inside the list.

**2nd EDIT:** This is for `API < 24`

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> indexes2 = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); ++i) {
            String key = list.get(i);
            if (indexes2.get(key) == null) {
                List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                list1.add(i);
                indexes2.put(key, list1);
            } else {
                List<Integer> list2 = indexes2.get(key);
                list2.add(i);
                indexes2.put(key, list2);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(indexes2);
```

This outputs:

```
{Sheep=[1, 5], Cow=[0, 3], Chicken=[4], Lamb=[2]}
```

**FIRST ANSWER:** This is used to filter values so you can **REMOVE** duplicates.

To do this you can use `HashSet` or `LinkedHashSet` like this:

```
ArrayList<String> list_with_duplicate_items = new ArrayList<String>();
list_with_duplicate_items.add("Cow");
list_with_duplicate_items.add("Sheep");
list_with_duplicate_items.add("Lamb");
list_with_duplicate_items.add("Chicken");
list_with_duplicate_items.add("Cow");
list_with_duplicate_items.add("Sheep");

HashSet<String> filter = new HashSet(list_with_duplicate_items);
ArrayList<String> new_list = new ArrayList<String>(filter); //or just add to your first ArrayList like list_with_duplicate_items = new ArrayList<String>(filter);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, but this removes the duplicates, I want to keep them (for some reason) and get the "real" positions. So I want the output to be "1. Cow; 5.Cow"

Comment: Ohh, sorry I didn't understand the question at first.

Comment: @Creesch2.0 I edited my comment, check this. Maybe it can help you.

Comment: Exactly the output that I wanted, but .computeIfAbsent is from API 24, and my min. API is 21. But I really appreciate your help and time

Comment: @Creesch2.0 there, another edit. I wrote it for you. This way it will do the same job if it's below API 24. But if it is above just use the first method since it's probably faster than my code.

Comment: I really really appreciate taking your time to answer my question, really appreciated, but again `putIfAbsent` is also API 24.

Comment: @Creesch2.0 oh my bad, I forgot to change. Just use.put(key, value) instead. Since we already did check with indexes2.get(key) == null, if that's true that object does not exist in the HashMap. So, .put(key, value) will work fine.

Comment: @Creesch2.0 Also if you want your output to be in order as input like if the Cow is first then Cow is first in the output just use LinkedHashMap instead of HashMap. Then output values will stay in the same order.